# Colorbox- how to get value from popup (Child.aspx) page to the parent (parent.aspx) page

Tags: jquery, vb.net, colorbox

I have 2 pages. parent.aspx and child.aspx. 
In parent.aspx, i use colorbox and send some value for the child.aspx to popup.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          $(".iframe").colorbox({ iframe: true, innerWidth: 700, innerHeight: 400});
      });


<a class="iframe" href="popup/AgreementIDwithCond.aspx?where=ProductCategory like '%' &field=AgreementID|<%=txtAgreementID.clientid%>">Search</a>
```

child.aspx will popup and shows ASPxGridView base on the value passing from parent.aspx.
User will select the data from ASPxGridView. the selected data need to send back to the parent page. I code it in child.aspx.vb page.

My problem is how can i get the value from child.aspx.vb and pass it to parent.aspx ?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to have a global variable in your parent document.

```
var formData;
```

Then your child document can write values to that variable:

```
parent.formData = "Hello";
```

Comment: i have tried but this global variable can only be use in the parent page only since the child page is in different url.

Comment: Did I not answer exactly what you asked? How to pass data from the child to the parent?

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
function update() {     $('#txtBox1', top.document).val('Test'); }
```